# Add event listener to Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, iframe

When the IFrame loads this code attaches `'click'` event to `'a'` tag.

```
            function AddEventListenerToFrame(iframe) 
            {
                var frame = $(iframe).get(0).contentDocument;
                $('a', frame).click(function (event) {
                    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
                });
            }
```

This works fine. But when the user clicks on the rendered menu and new partial is rendered, the clicks does not work anymore.

So, the issue is : event does not work on the new elements.

How to attach the same event for new rendered content ??

Comment: `But when the user clicks on the rendered menu and new partial is rendered` so you mean the event does not work on the new elements... correct ?

Comment: Yes. That's right. I edited my question.

Comment: have you tried using - ` $(frame).on('click','a',function (event) {
                    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
                });`

Comment: @JithinRajPR what's that ?

Comment: well of course it will not bind because the elements are new. Code does not magically run. Either you need to rebind or event delegation....

Comment: Yes. That's clear. Do you have any idea how to add event listener to the new-rendered elements ?

Comment: you can use on method in jquery....that works with newly added elements also

Comment: @MukulSharma can you provide some example/link  ?

Comment: Go through this -https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @BobSwager - what type of elements u are adding dynamically?

Comment: @MukulSharma partial views.  I make it work. This way : 

 `var frame = $(iframe).get(0).contentDocument;
            $(frame).on('click', 'a', function () { `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148906/discussion-between-mukulsharma-and-bob-swager).

Comment: I solved my problem :) Enjoy ;)